# How to re-initialize Vue 3 scaffolding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

There are `npm init vue@latest` and `npm create vue@3` to scaffold new Vue project.

I know there is a command that re-initializes the scaffolding command so you can add, for example, TypeScript or Cypress. Can't find it even though I remember I pulled it off once, but can't remember how I did it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can remember this was possible in vue2 when using vue-cli, where you could do `vue add xxx`. I think this is no longer possible with vue3, you just redo the commands to scaffold a new project or just do `npm install` of individual packages that you need.